# My first java project

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I 'm making a project in Java for the university and I have an input like this :

```
i 4         //that are the iteration 

a nissan car motor -1      // "a" means add operation "nissan" is the element and "car e motor"  
                                         // are the tags associated to nissan

a apple fruit iphone macbook -1  

a peach fruit color -1   

s fr -1               // "s" is the subtag that I have to find in the tag

i 3

a soccer ball player -1

a volley ball shoes -1

s bal -1

END                // "END" is the end of input
```

Output :

```
2

2
```

Because at the first iteration it has find two elements that have tags that starts with "fr"
and at the second iteration it has find two elements that have tags that starts with "bal".

```
class main 
{
    private static boolean trovato;

    public static void main (String args [] ) throws IOException 
    {
        HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map = new HashMap <String,HashSet<String>> (); 
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        HashSet<String> totale = new HashSet <String> () ;

        String line ;
        String numiter;
        Integer numiter2  = 0 ;
        String[] parts = null ;

        HashSet<String> hs   = new HashSet<String>  () ;
        HashSet<String> tmp = new HashSet<String>  () ;
        Vector <Integer> conti = new Vector<Integer> ();

        boolean entrato = false ;

        line = stdin.readLine();

        while (!line.equals("<END>"))
        {
            if (line.startsWith("i"))
            {
                map.clear();
                hs.clear();
                totale.clear();
            }

            parts = line.split("[\\s\\-1]");      

            if (parts[0].equals("a"))               
            {

                hs.add(parts[1]);

                for (int r = 2 ; r < parts.length ; r++)    
                {

                    map.put(parts[r], hs);                                              
                }

            }


            System.out.println("totale" + totale.size ());
            if (parts[0].equals("s"))
            {
                entrato = false ;   
                for (String key : map.keySet())                                 
                {
                    if (key.startsWith(parts[1]))                                   
                    {
                        entrato = true ;            
                        totale.addAll(map.get(key));                                
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(totale.size ());
            }
            line = stdin.readLine();
        }
    }   
}
```

The code works but my teacher wants a more efficient way to do this.I don't know how to do it .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help me ! SHould I use a SortedMap r a Treemap .Which is better for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

for future reference try to keep your questions more specific than this. Debugging is you job; I would recommend reviewing the concepts taught in class before coming here. We prefer to answer a more specific question than this. Feel free to get in contact with me if you need further assistance.

Comment: I don't write english very well . I ' m sorry .So you didn't understand my problem ?

Comment: You just kind of hurled a bunch of code at us. The question isn't very specific, so I really don't see what you're getting at